# When should I apply template in constructor or connectedCallback

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, html5-template

When should I apply template in `constructor` or `connectedCallback` ? When I do it in callback sometimes `attributeChangedCallback` is called before and i can't query for elements.

```
export class TestElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //here ?
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    //here ?
  }
}
```

I would like to know where and why it is better.

Here is a snipped of template apply code

```
let t = document.createElement('template');
t.innerHTML = require('template.html');
this.appendChild(t.content.cloneNode(true));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use Shadow DOM you should not insert template in the `constructor()` callback.

Therefore you should append it only in `connectedCallback()`.

Anyways `attributeChangedCallback()` can be called before or after the above callbacks depending on how your custom element is used. So you should always make a test before trying to query some inner elements.

Comment: What about when I do use shadow DOM ? is it better then to do it in constructor ? what about creating shadow dom ? should i do it in constructor or connected callback ?

Comment: you cannot access/modify the normal DOM in constructor but you can attach a shadow DOM (and the template inside) in the constructor.